# Convert int to 16 bit unsigned short

Tags: python

I want to trim an integer to 16 bit word (unsigned short) in Python. Something like following does not work

```
word = array("H")
word.insert(0,0x19c6acc6)
```

Comment: Read about [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html), it might help you.

Comment: you want this??  hex(ord("H"))
'0x48'

Comment: No. I want to convert 0x19c6acc6 to "unsigned short" basically trim it to "0xacc6"

Comment: Then put that example in your question.

Comment: `0x19c6acc6 % 65536`

Comment: you can do `value & 0xffff`

Comment: aaah. Thanks Niklas. How did I miss this. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The classical way is to extract the relevant bits using a mask:

```
>>> hex(0x19c6acc6 & 0xffff)
'0xacc6'
```

Answer (score 10):

Use [`ctypes.c_ushort`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_ushort):

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> word.insert(0, ctypes.c_ushort(0x19c6acc6).value)
>>> word
array('H', [44230])
```

If NumPy is available then:

```
>>> numpy.ushort(0x19c6acc6)
44230
```