# Python convert a value to 16 bit 2's complement

Tags: python, short, twos-complement

Is it possible to convert a value(int) in python to signed 2's complement 16 bit format? I am looking for a functionality similar to `short` used in Java.

```
value = (short) v;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert int to 16 bit unsinged short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171522/convert-int-to-16-bit-unsinged-short)

Comment: I would like it to be signed short to represent values from -32,768 to 32,767

Answer (score 0):

I figured it using Numpy.

```
value = np.short(v)
```